# Rails - association with another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users table(and a user model). In my scenario, a user can have multiple identities. I.e. user michael1 (id = 1) can be connected to michael2 (id = 2) and michael3 (id = 3).

I created a table to store these connections. I called it user_relations and it has: id, user_id, related_user_id columns. In the previous example I'll have:

user_id | related_user_id

1       |   2

1       |   3

In users model I defined: has_many :user_relations, and in user_relation I defined: belongs_to :users.

Now, I want that when I have a user object I would be able to get:

current_user.user_relations - and get all users objects that are connected according to the table. In previous example, if I have current_user as user with id 1, I would like to get users with id 2 and 3.

How can I achieve that?

BTW - I have an id because I saw that without it, I am not able to use destroy_all. If anyone has an insight regarding this also, I am open to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. If I missed something you can look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for details:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_relations
  has_many :related_users, :through=> :user_relations
end

class UserRelations< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
  belongs_to :related_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "related_user_id"
end
```

Comment: user_relation is the mapping table. It has two foreign keys pointing to the users table. Since rails usually understands the name of the referenced table from the name of the foreign key and you can't use 2 similar column names, you use a different name and explicitly tell rails that you're pointing to the users table. Let me know if there's something else you don't understand in this sample.

Comment: And why did you use related_user and NOT related_users with s?